# Go to classic results page link is wrong, where do I change it?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, modern-experience, sharepoint-search

In the modern search at the bottom you get the "go to classic results page".

In my case it says `...tenant.sharepoint.com/search/results.aspx` while the correct address should be `...tenant.sharepoint.com/search/PAGES/results.aspx`.

I went to many places to correct this (mostly the search site collection or the main root site collection in search settings) but it does not work, it is still redirecting wrong and giving a 'page not found' error.

Comment: This issue is there since the beginning

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a **known issue** in SharePoint Online Modern experience.

I have created a support request with Microsoft. I will update you once I get response from Microsoft team.

**Update from Microsoft Team**:

> After speaking with several people in my advanced team, they have discovered that there is a bug within SharePoint regarding that search link. **When you are searching in the new SharePoint, there should not be a link saying to `Go to classic results page`**.
>
> This link should not exist and there lies the bug. Everyone in my office are experiencing this very same thing. Our engineers have been made aware and a bug report has been filed regarding this bug.

**Future Plan**:

> **We do plan on removing that link from the Modern page**. Next steps for you, please go back to the old experience for searching older sites. Meaning, please do not search for sites in the modern page that were made in the classic page and vice versa. As for when the update would take effect, it could be on the next update. I do not have that information on when the update will happen.
>
> You can go to our [SharePoint Uservoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/38642506-link-to-go-to-classic-results-page-on-search-res) and vote for the engineers to fix this issue.

Comment: I noticed this and was able to fix it 12 months ago and I do remember I fixed it again 3-4 months ago. Now it reverted back to not working.

Comment: How did you fix it? It will be helpful for many of us if you let us know.

Comment: I have update from microsoft team that it is bug and they are planning to remove this link from modern search page. Check updated answer for more information.

Comment: You need to go to the main root site Site Settings, then SEARCH SETTINGS and put https://TENANT.sharepoint.com/search/pages (as suggested in the note below this box). I used to do that and get it to work, but now it is not, it means this value is not affecting the link. And in the past, it is true that there was not 'go to classic results page' when searching in modern sites, but there was when you were searching from the 'Sharepoint' page (https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx)

Comment: Yes, what you were doing before is working for me also. And when you asked this question, I tried doing the same and it was not working. That's why I have not suggested you this approach(even when it was in my mind).

Comment: And now Microsoft team is planning to remove this link from modern search page as they are saying this is a bug. Hope this clarifies. (I have added all responses from microsoft team in my answer).

Comment: Does this answer helpful? If Yes, please upvote and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).